# How do I eliminate error message 1064 when trying to create table with BLOB type columns?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error for this table. I've never created a table using blob's before so I do not understand the error message. Can someone explain the error?

```
CREATE TABLE `teamc`.`newsletter` (
    `title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    `subtitle` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
     `jpg` BLOB BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `pdf` BLOB BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `title` , `date` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

MySQL gives me the following error:

> Documentation 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL, `pdf` BLOB BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`tit' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

BINARY is a type, BLOB is a type - and you cannot specify multiple types for the same column. You pick one:

```
CREATE TABLE `newsletter` (
    `title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    `subtitle` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
    `jpg` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `pdf` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `title` , `date` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: appendix to your answer: BLOB = Binary Large Object so `BLOB Binary` would be in either way redundant..

Comment: Thank you. I was under the assumption you needed to set a blob to binary because it was one. I see now that this is redundant.